# Renaming a file in pyton using a variable

Tags: python

hey all hope someone can help!

Im using the below to find the most recent file downloaded in the specified directory. I need to be able to rename the file from how it comes to a specic name - any help would be appreciated.

```
import glob
import os
download_path = f'C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Downloads'
list_of_files = glob.glob(f"{download_path}\\*")
latest_file: str = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

os.rename("latest_file", "??????????")

the file needs to be called sf-admin-term

Thanks!

Comment: What is happening now with your script?

Comment: f-strings don't exist in python-2.7

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#option-1-formatting

Comment: The file runs and i get the print at the end of the path

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for *os.rename()* ? In case you can't find it it's here:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ext = latest_file.split('.')[-1]
os.rename(latest_file, f"{download_path}/new_file.{ext}")
```

Comment: this doesn't seems to be working

Comment: The script runs, no errors but does not change the name of the file

Comment: `download_path = f'C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Downloads'
list_of_files = glob.glob(f"{download_path}\\*")
latest_file: str = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

ext = latest_file.split('.')[-1]
os.rename(latest_file, f"{download_path}/sf-admin-term.{ext}")`